# Hide an entire row of table where a cell is empty

Tags: css, html

How can I hide the whole row if a cell of the second column is empty Using CSS?

```
   <table class="maintable" >
  <tr>
<td class="tb_1c">Brand:</td>
<td class="tb_2c">{{ITEMBRAND}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="tb_1c">Part Number: </td>
<td class="tb_2c">{{ITEMSKU}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="tb_1c">Part Type:</td>
<td class="tb_2c">{{U_ITEMCAT}}</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="tb_1c">Size</td>
<td class="tb_2c"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have it working with Jquery

```
$("tr").filter(function(){return $("td:last",this).is(":empty");}).hide();
```

But the platform where the table is showing doesn't like it.

Comment: I am not sure if this will be possible with only css, can you use JavaScript?

Comment: You can hide td, but not sure if whole row using CSS. `tr td:last:empty {display: none;}`

Comment: I agree with both of the answer above. You can hide your cell, but not a whole row with css just by controling of a cell is empty..

Comment: I just posted you a new answer. I hope it suits your needs :)

Comment: @Callie: You can, check my answer :) Ops i mean with js / jQuery yes. Not only in css of course :)

Comment: Where are all the other answers? They have deleted them :O

Comment: @AlexIncarnati I said you can't do it with css. Never said you can't do it with jQuery :P Of course the solution for this problem is to work with jQuery

Comment: I just edited...i forgot to update the jsfiddle. Please recheck :)

Comment: @Callie, I know that's why I edited my comment before. Sorry about that.

Comment: What do you mean by “the platform where the table is showing doesn't like it”? There is no CSS solution. Do you mean that your jQuery solution does not work under some conditions? Then you need to ask a new question about it, with sufficient facts disclosed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the :not(), :has() and :empty selectors combined like this:

```
$("tr").not(":has(td:nth-child(2):not(:empty))").hide();
```

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/fA6S8/2/

Comment: Probably slower than `$('td.tb_2c:empty').closest('tr').hide()`

Comment: Probably, but in your case you are relying on the class present on that html structure, you could rewrite yours making it reusable :)

Comment: I leave that up to you. With votes comes responsibility!

Answer (score 1):

As per using jquery:

```
 $("tr:has(td.tb_2c:empty)").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no CSS solution, because currently you cannot select an element on the basis of what elements it contains.

If you have problems in implementing a JavaScript solution, please ask a new question, showing the relevant HTML and JavaScript code that reproduce the problem.